# Regular Expression in Python not matching correctly

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract data from a string using regular expressions in Python.

The string is "15% Off your first order". I want to extract 15 from this string. For this, I am doing -

```
import re
pattern = r'.*(\d+)\s*\%.*off.*'
string = '15% Off your first order'
m = re.match(pattern, string, re.I)
print m.group(1)
```

However, this returns `5` and not `15`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is here

```
.*(\d+)
```

`.*` is greedy. So the actual matching happens like this.

```
r'.*(\d+)\s*\%.*off.*'
```

`.*` first matches the entire string, since it is greedy and checks if the RegEx is satisfied. Since it is not satisfied, it leaves the last character and checks to see if it matches the RegEx. So, it does this continuously and matches `1` and finds that `(\d+)\s*\%.*off.*` matches the rest of the string. So, `.*` actually matches till `1` and leaving `\d+` to match 5. That is why it is giving `5`. Change it to non-greedy like this

```
r'.*?(\d+)\s*\%.*off.*'
```

Now, `.*` is non-greedy because of `?`. So, it will match as minimum as possible. So, it will match nothing here, since `\d+` matches 15.

**Note:** As you see, it has to iteratively try all the possible matches. So it is very inefficient. You can actually write it like this

```
r'.*?(\d+)\s*?\%\s*?off.*'
```

Since we use non-greedy operators everywhere, it will be better than the original greedy version.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.*` from your pattern and use `search` instead of `match` to let the match start anywhere:

```
pattern = r'(\d+)\s*\%.*off.*'
m = re.search(pattern, string, re.I)
```

Comment: I have kept that because the title could be `Get 15% off your first order`. Any ideas how to match both?

Comment: What I wrote should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can you this regex to match:

```
^\d+(?=% Off)
```

It makes sure that the number begins the string and follow the number is `% Off`